# Can not read property length when adding escape in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-injection

Report bug:

#### 1. Description:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "db"
});
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database Connected!");
});
```

When adding escape like this:

```
var sql =
  "SELECT * FROM tb WHERE col_1 = '"
  +con.escape(req.params.val_1)
  +"' AND col_2 = '"+con.escape(req.params.val_2)
  +"' "
```

#### 2. Problem:

> Cannot read property length when calling `result.length` and it drop out.

Is there something behind the scenes in this?

Answer (score 0):

req.params will get result: `value` BUT con.escape(req.params.val_1)  ... get `'value'` -> so error happen. Do replace `'` will make it done!